# FTP Several Files

Tags: c#, ftp

I have what would seem like a common problem, but I cannot find an appropriate solution on any forums. I need to FTP an entire directory structure using .NET. I have found several code examples all of which show how you can FTP a single file by creating an **FtpWebRequest** object. Unfortunately,  there is no information on how to deal with several files. Do I simply create a **FtpWebRequest** object for every single file?

Answer (score 1):

You can always call a new Process with a command like using for example WinSCP (open source FTP client)
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/start

Perhaps call the synchronize operation:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize

Comment: This question has some other input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693265/how-to-synchronise-ftp-directory-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

If there's a shorter way, I don't know what it is.

I wrote my code to handle each file one by one. If you are dealing with entire directory structures, that would entail processing each directory one by one as well.