# Syncing folders from local computer to remote computer?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have installed Bitnami wamp stack on my local computer as well as the remote computer.

I do all the development locally, What I would want is to sync the public htdocs folder of the local system with the remote system.

FTP is slow and has to be done manually. What i want is a single sync command, similar to github push and pull. I don't want to use github either.

Basically, i am looking for a solution that can sync modified files only, instead, of uploading complete folders again and again using FTP.

Comment: There's FTP clients that can do this, search e.g. for `ftp sync` (and then the name of your OS/platform)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693265/how-to-synchronise-ftp-directory-from-command-line

Comment: Just looked, WinSCP has sync capabilities...